# Items added to list are non-reactive in version 2 of Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Vue 1.0 I used to add items to an array used in a v-for by simply calling `items.push({})` as you can see here:

http://jsbin.com/figiluteni/1/edit?html,js,output

The exact same code in Vue 2.0 inserts a non-reactive object to the array:

http://jsbin.com/zuwihahiwa/1/edit?html,js,output

(Note that the newly added items are not live updated when edited)

```
    <button @click="items.push({})">Add item</button>
```

I know that Vue inserts hooks on arrays when initialized, but being a Vue model binding that creates the new item's "name" property, I thought it could be automatically hooked like in Vue 1.

I find this new behavior very inconvenient, for it forces me to add a prototype of the object I want to add in Vue's data and clone it:

http://jsbin.com/bamasobuti/1/edit?html,js,output

In Vue's data:

```
    item_prototype: {id: null, name: ""}
```

In the template:

```
    <button @click="items.push(_.clone(item_prototype))">Add item</button>
```

My question is:  Is there a recommended way of adding elements without having to keep a prototype of an empty element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According Vue's documentation, `v-model="item.prop"` is just syntactic sugar for:

`v-bind:value="item.prop" v-on:input="item.prop = $event.target.value"`.

To make it work, just stop using 
`v-model="item.prop"` and use this instead:

`:value="item.prop" @input="$set(item,'prop',$event.target.value)"`

Answer (score 2):

The change is not related to reactivity system change, but rather how `v-model` works in 2.0: it no longer magically creates non-existent paths and make them reactive for you.

This change is intended to force you to think about your data shape and to make your application state more predictable, similar to how you are expected to declare the reactive properties in your component's `data` option.

If I were you, I'd create a method and just do `this.items.push({ id: null, name: '' })`. There's no need to clone it.

Comment: Thanks Evan!  It's an honor to have you answering!
Just to read more about this... Is this design choice discussed anywhere? (a Github issue or in the documentation, etc?)